# Problem with map insertion using goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm new to Golang and learning to use goroutine. I'm trying to insert into a map[int]string concurrently many strings by goroutines

```
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"
       "sync"
   )

   func input(m map[int]string, i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
       m[i] = fmt.Sprintf("line %d\n", i+1)
       fmt.Print(m[i])
       wg.Done()
   }

   func GetMap(m map[int]string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        wg.Add(5)
        for i:=0; i<5; i++{
             go input(m, i, wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
   }

   func main(){
       var wg sync.WaitGroup
       m1 := make(map[int]string)
       GetMap(m1, &wg)
       fmt.Print(m1)
   }
```

**Expected:**
line 1
line 2
line 5
line 3
line 4
map[0:line 1
 1:line 2
 2:line 3
 3:line 4
 4:line 5
]
**Results**: It's different every time, sometimes it's the expected result sometimes it's like this:
line 5
fatal error: concurrent map writes
line 1
line 2
So why is the result different every time i recompile? Thank you

Comment: Why is lt like what? Randomized order? Or why do you get the error?

Comment: Which one? The expected result is random because the routines for insertion finish at different time I believe

Comment: What do you mean, "which one"? Which error? The one you're getting, "fatal error: concurrent map writes".

Comment: Ah my bad, I got what you mean now. Yeah my question is why sometimes it runs normally and sometimes it raises errors

Comment: Because it's not safe to write to a map concurrently. You need an explicit synchronization of some sort (a mutex, for example)

Comment: So there's no way to insert many values into a map or array at the same time?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a race condition on your map. You are sharing it across multiple goroutines without using any synchronization mechanism. Protect it with a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex).

Then, you cannot expect any given order when storing values  in  a map. In fact, Go's map [spec](http://%20https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) says:

> A map is an unordered group of elements of one type

If order matters for your application, then use a slice.